# Why does git think this is a conflict after cherrypick?

Tags: git, conflict, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit on windows, i have 2 branches. But when I cherrypick commits from the other branch, quite often I get 'confilict' reports. But when I tried to resolve these 'conflicts', a lot of times I am quite confused and angry (like the case in the screen shot below), how can this be conflict? One file doesn't have anything while the other file has some new lines, this couldn't be more simppler. Why git treat this as a conflict? Can anyone explain? Thanks..

[image: why this was marked 'conflict' by git?]

Comment: I think you should post this to the Git dev community somehow, as I see no conflict at all, and it might be a bug. See http://git-scm.com/community

Comment: @SzG There _is_ a conflict...look closely.  The `toString()` method is in conflict due to the cherry-pick.

Comment: It's not in conflict. It's simply new code in a clearly defined context.

Comment: I find conflicts are usually (not always, but usually) clearer if I set `merge.conflictstyle = diff3`.  This shows not just the two branch-tip versions, but also the merge-base version.  It's worth trying (you can run `git -c merge.conflictstyle=diff3 checkout -m thefile` while in the middle of this conflict, to see what the diff3 style produces, but note that this will undo your resolution if you've resolved the conflict already).

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced a case where there is a real conflict behind an apparent nothing-vs-something non-conflict.

Base commit:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Next commit on master removes baz

```
foo
baz
```

Next commit on another branch adds something at the same position

```
foo
spam
bar
baz
```

When I try to merge the branch into master, I get this conflict:

```
foo         
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======     
spam        
bar         
>>>>>>> plus
baz
```

Apparently a false alarm, nothing on master, added something on the other branch.

But in reality, the alarm is not false, but the information put into the file by Git is definitely false: it lists `bar`, removed on master, as added on the other branch.

So Git IS buggy, but in a very subtle and surprising way. They apparently try to fit some information into the `>>>>>>>=======<<<<<<<` notation, but a remove-add conflict does not fit into it, as it needs additional info about the merge base. Or any other way to tell "added by them" from "kept by them".

Answer (score 0):

When you cherry-pick a commit from another branch, you are making a *new* commit on that branch.  As with any commit, there is the potential for merge conflicts.

I believe the source of your confusion is that the commit which you are cherry-picking is already sitting in another branch, and you already resolved all merge conflicts for this commit.  So intuitively it seems as though this commit should be portable to another branch without any problems.  The problem is that when you cherry pick this commit to another branch, the *base* on which that commit sits has changed.  Therefore, you can (and often do) get merge conflicts.

Comment: The actual text between the conflict markers indicates no conflict at all. The conflict is between nothing and something in the same context, which is the very definition of no conflict. I'm baffled too.

Comment: In your image above there is a _massive_ conflict, with about 30 lines of new code coming in from the cherry pick commit `9bd0f1f...`

Comment: No, that's not a conflict at all. It's just a chunk of new code added to a clearly defined context in the source branch.

Comment: @SzG Yes, it's a conflict.  The method exists in the cherry-pick and either doesn't exist in `HEAD` locally, or is in a different place where Git cannot reconcile it.  Adding code doesn't have to break that code in order for it to be a conflict.

Comment: @SzG To give you a better example, imagine that the method inserted were code from a language where _order_ strongly matters.  In this case, adding `toString()` in a certain _order_ might break the code, even though there are no visible "conflicts."  Git is basically screaming and saying "I can cleanly put this method here, but I don't know if this will break your code."  In this case, it might not break the code, but Git doesn't speak Java, it speaks Git.